# Managing DNS on CentOS 6.4

Tags: centos6

I am a bit new to this and I look ahead to get answers on how I can do this. It is my first challange and I look ahead to get an assistance from anyone out there if they wish to give me a hand.

I have a server (Intel SR1300) that I need to use it for my own internal use with this server.
I have recently install OwnCloud and I will love to use OwnCloud I want to use this application on my own network not necessarily used on the world wide web.

Now my problem I have is to setup the DNS Server and I don't know what IP I can use. What I need to do is that anyone who connects to my network can manage to access the webserver and use OwnCloud without it being published on the internet. so if I use 192.x.x.1 as a default manually configured. If this ip is to be used as a default gateway from the DHCP what other ip I can use with for the DNS Server as the domain name resolver?

Also how can I setup the DNS for internal use without using global IP?

I will appreciate if you help me resolve this issue.

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is little confusing, still let me try to answer.

(1) First of all you need an external DNS to be setup. Which means your  www.test.com should be mapped to your public ISP.  Again this is not necessary, if you want the outsiders to contact via IP.

(2) Next coming to your internal DNS setup. You need to install and configure bind services. Here is a nice link, which shows on how to setup a private DNS server on your local server. 
http://www.krizna.com/centos/how-to-install-dns-server-in-centos-6/

(3) Finally you have to add a forward rule on your firewall/router with the external and internal port you want to map. Eg Let say users from outside wanted to call http://www.test.com:8080. Then you have to forward your port 8080 to your opencloud services dashboard services.

Hope this should be a good start. Again may not be a clear solution in your case.

Comment: I have tried to follow the instruction but am still stuck with one issue. The dhcp server work and even the host works ok. For example if I use hostname name srv.nameact.com instead of localhost but if I tried to access it from another computer it still does not work. However I will like to know if there is any other software that I need to install so that I can access the webserver from anyother location I will appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to follow the instruction but am still stuck with one issue. The dhcp server work and even the host works ok. For example if I use hostname name srv.nameact.com instead of localhost but if I tried to access it from another computer it still does not work. However I will like to know if there is any other software that I need to install so that I can access the webserver from anyother location I will appreciate.